# Test hypotheses using the Neyman-Pearson test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Given a sample of $X_1, X_2$. $X_1 = 0.35, X_2 = 0.342$. Test the hypothesis $H_0: X_i \sim U(-1/2, 1/2)$ against the alternative $H_1: X_i \sim N(0, 1/4)$ based on the Neyman-Pearson lemma. The significance level can be taken as 0.1
Find the probabilities of errors of the 1st and 2nd kind.

There is no problem at the first steps, first we find the ratio of the likelihood functions:
$l(x) = 1(X_{(1)} \ge -1/2)\cdot1(X_{(2)} \le 1/2) \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \exp(2\cdot(X_1 ^2 + X_2^2))$

And next steps:
$\begin{equation*}
\phi(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
   1 &\text{l(x)>c}\\
   \gamma &\text{$l(x) = c$}\\
   0 &\text{$l(x) < c$}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$

$\alpha = E_0(\phi(x)) = P_0(l(x) > c) + \gamma \cdot P_0(l(x) = c)$

How can we correctly consider cases of the value $c$ and what are the resulting probabilities?
I am a student and so far poorly versed in this topic, I would be grateful for a more or less detailed solution

Comment: Do you mean "Neyman" by chance?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I used a translator

Comment: You would consider the distribution of $l$ (or some suitable function of it) under $H_0$ to find a suitable $c$ such that the rejection rate was no more than $\alpha$ when $H_0$ was true. However, given that $\mathcal{L}_0$ (the likelihood under $H_0$) is on the numerator in your expression for $l$, shouldn't you reject for *small* values of the likelihood ratio, not large ones?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.